# How to pivot a grouped object with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below table:

```
+-----------+------+-------+
| member_id | year | count |
+-----------+------+-------+
|         1 | 2012 |     1 |
|         1 | 2013 |     0 |
|         1 | 2014 |     1 |
|         2 | 2012 |     2 |
|         2 | 2013 |     0 |
|         2 | 2014 |     1 |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

and i'd like to turn it into this:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| member_id | count_2012 | count_2013 | count_2014 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|         1 |          1 |          0 |          1 |
|         2 |          2 |          0 |          1 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I tried grouping and then pivoting and also just pivoting, but the pivot requires and aggfunc, and I'm not trying to change the values, just reshape it.

Comment: `df.pivot('member_id', 'year', 'count')` or `df.set_index(['member_id', 'year']).unstack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.pivot(index='member_id',columns='year', values='count')
```

If you dont want to have member_id as index:

```
df = df.pivot(index='member_id',columns='year', values='count').reset_index()
```